# Include redshift jdbc driver: Unable to instantiate driver class "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

We use Wildfly 10 with a postgres datasource (postgres driver is deliverd in /modules folder) and in addition, a Redshift DB should be attached.

So I followed [Configure a JDBC Connection with Apache Maven](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html) :
My parent POM includes therefore:

```
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>redshift</id>
        <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I know deploy me .war file, the following warning appears very early in the log:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.2)
WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazon/redshift/core/jdbc42/PGJDBC42DriverImpl
```

So no wonder that later on, if I try to access the DB, I get

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-64) java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift://....
ERROR [stderr] (default task-64)    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
ERROR [stderr] (default task-64)    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
```

So what am I doing wrong? The driver is packaged in the .war, this is for sure, otherwise, there would not be a trial to instantiate it during deployment.
Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `redshift-jdbc42` dependency has been packaged with "inner" JAR files, and this causes problems for class loading in some contexts.  Try replacing

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>${amazon.redshift.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-redshift</artifactId>
        <version>${amazonaws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
        <version>${amazon.redshift.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

(Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263573)

Comment: Thanks very much! A little remark: `${amazonaws.sdk.version}` is not the same for both; the version nummering differs.

Comment: Yea.  As you can see, the above uses `${amazonaws.sdk.version}`  and `${amazon.redshift.version}`.

Comment: O yes, sorry... I was too blind seeing a difference ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Updating Redshift dependency in build.gradle solved my issue

```
          // AWS
        dependency "com.amazon.redshift:redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk:1.2.54.1082"
        dependencySet(group: "com.amazonaws", version: "1.11.688") {
            entry "aws-java-sdk-s3"
            entry "aws-java-sdk-sts"
            entry "aws-java-sdk-redshift"

        };
```